# How to convert PdfCopy to byte array in java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I try to merge 2 PDF files into one PDF. I did it with `PdfCopy.addPage(...)`
now I have good PdfCopy and I want to get it as byte array.

How can I do it?
This is my code:

```
public void mergePDF(ActionEvent actionEvent)  throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    String[] files = { "C:\\first.pdf","C:\sescond"};
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\myMergedFile.pdf"));
    document.open();
    PdfReader reader;
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
        n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
            copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
        }
        copy.freeReader(reader);
        reader.close();
    }    
    document.close();
}
```

Thanks.

soha

Comment: You are not saying which library you have used. Please add a tag and or upadet your question with this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using a `FileOutputStream` in

```
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\myMergedFile.pdf"));
```

simply use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, baos);
```

After closing the document you can retrieve the byte array:

```
document.close();
byte[] documentBytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

If you want to have the document both as byte array and as file, simply add

```
Files.write(new File("PATH_AND_NAME_OF_FILE.pdf").toPath(), documentBytes);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main( String[] args )
   {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream=null;

    File file = new File("C:\\testing.txt");

    byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) file.length()];

    try {
        //convert file into array of bytes
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    fileInputStream.read(bFile);
    fileInputStream.close();

    for (int i = 0; i < bFile.length; i++) {
        System.out.print((char)bFile[i]);
        }

    System.out.println("Done");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Nice, but I don't want use path of the PDF, I have use with convert.

Comment: Unless you are bound to a very old Java version, you might want to make this a one-liner using `java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Path)`.